# Android onClick start's two animation, should only start one

Tags: java, android

Depending on which animation I click first, the second animation will always set off the first animation. I have no idea what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Test extends Activity {
    ImageView img_left;
    ImageView img_right;
    Button left;
    Button right;
    TranslateAnimation moveup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        moveup = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -900);
        moveup.setDuration(2000);
        moveup.setFillAfter(true);
        left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left);
        right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right);
        img_left = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_left);
        img_right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_right);
        right.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                img_right.startAnimation(moveup);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });

        left.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                img_left.startAnimation(moveup);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "left", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".First" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0000EE"
            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0000EE"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_left"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cue1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_right"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cue2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show us your layout xml. You might have your IDs set to the same value.

Comment: Triple checked, and they are all set correctly, but I'll add it anyway. Maybe I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Create two different `Animation` objects with the same properties, one for the left and one for the right, or call `setAnimation(null)` on the other view before you start it.  In other words:

```
    right.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            img_left.setAnimation(null);
            img_right.startAnimation(moveup);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "right", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });

    left.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            img_right.setAnimation(null);
            img_left.startAnimation(moveup);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "left", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
```

`Animation` objects are attached to their views when `setAnimation()` or `startAnimation()` is called.  By starting both views attached to the same `Animation` instance, the animation has the possibility of affecting the drawing of both views as it runs.  Views only pay attention to the current state of the animation when they are invalidated, so this doesn't necessarily mean they will always animate together.  But if your code gets into a situation where both `ImageView` instances are invalid while the `Animation` runs, they will both respond to the translation.

Comment: `moveup.setAnimationListener(null);` didn't work. Creating two animation objects did though. I feel like two objects is unnecessary though, or is my thought process just incorrect?

Comment: What if I was making a game and I wanted bullets to fly all with the same animation. Would I create a new animation object for each or is there anyway to affect a view with an animation without affecting the other views that have already been put into animation? Thanks

Comment: Not clearing the listener...the animation; I updated the answer with an example.  You only want that animation attached to any one view at a time.  Creating one for each view is not the worst thing, they aren't heavyweight objects, and you would certainly need to if they were all running simultaneously because they would be at different points in the animation.  The `Animation` object keeps state of how far along the animation is to completion and what that means for the transformation.  Admittedly, it's a little awkward, but this is why Android 3.0+ doesn't use this animation system anymore.

Comment: Wait, so Android 3.0 doesn't use this anymore... what if I'm developing specifically for 3.0 and up?

Comment: Then you are probably better off moving to the newer property animation system.  The older system still works, but the overall API of property animation is much better: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Answer (score 0):

try using >> `new View.OnClickListener()` in place of `new OnClickListener()`